# Hexadecimal Floating-point literals

Tags: java, floating-point, hex

How does `0x12.2P2` equal 72.5?

I know that the value following the P, called the binary exponent, indicates the power-of-two by which the number is multiplied?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`0x12.2P2` is 0x122 / 16<sub>10</sub> * 2<sup>2</sup>

- 0x122 = 290<sub>10</sub>
- divided by 16<sub>10</sub> = 18.125<sub>10</sub>
- multiplied by 2<sup>2</sup> leads to 72.5<sub>10</sub>

---

More formally (?), for the part *before* the `P`, you can use this very classic conversion table:

```
     decimal point here  ▼
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-+-----+-----+-----+
| 16³ | 16² | 16¹ | 16⁰ | | 16⁻¹| 16⁻²| 16⁻³|
+-----------------------------------------+
|     |     |  1  |  2  |.|  2  |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-+-----+-----+-----+
```

So 0x12.2 is 1⨯16¹+2x16⁰+2⨯16⁻¹ = 18.125

Comment: I think you mean 290 instead of 190.

Comment: @Eran Damn! Stupid typo... Thank you for pointing that out !

Comment: I get 18.125 for dividing 290 by 16 in decimal, and 72.52 for multiplying 18.13 by 4. I recommend replacing "18.13" with "18.125" in both places where it appears.

Comment: @Patricia Thank you. I didn't even noticed than my desktop calculator has rounded the result. How silly am I this evening...